# Different HDD sounds in same laptops

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, noise, system-sounds

I have bought 5 new Lenovo ideapad h330 laptops together. 3 of them are very silent and 2 of them have HDD noise sounds. Maybe two times louder than the other 3 laptops. But seems all of them work fine.

I like to know do those two more noisy laptops have problem?

EDIT: When I was working with one of them I noticed tik-tik sounds in every 5-10 seconds. I could hear the sound in normal usage but when I checked the other laptop it's sound was lower and I must focused more and go nearer to laptop to hear the sound.

Comment: Need more details. When are you hearing the noises and what kinds of noises are they? Some sounds are normal, some indicate a problem.

Comment: I think the sound look usual, but the problem is that I think sounds in 2 of them are 2 times louder than the others. And one of them has a tik-tik sound in every 5 or 10 seconds I think.

Comment: Can you update your original question to include this information? Comments are often deleted, so it's best to put all the details in the question itself.

Comment: You said "new". Contact Lenovo Support and ask for replacements. Modern hard drives are generally quiet and do not tick.

Comment: @John: I am not sure if there is a problem or not? Maybe they used two different HDD brands in their products for example?

Comment: Ticking is bad. See my answer, but I've never seen a hard drive that ticks that didn't fail soon afterwards.

Comment: there is a purpose in ticking hard drives. even after they failed. https://youtu.be/Oym7B7YidKs

Answer (score 1):

Some variation in sound between devices is not unusual, as there could be slight differences in the alignment of the drives in their bays which could cause more or less vibration, which might sound like a faint hum as the drive starts up. It's also normal to hear a soft rattling or clattering noise when the drive is working hard, such as during bootup. Disk fragmentation can increase this noise significantly, but that is unlikely in a new machine.

If you are hearing basically the same noises from all the machines, and the difference is just in how loud they are, that may just be a difference in the quality of the mounting, or a loose connection, not necessarily a serious problem. Nevertheless, if the noise is loud enough to be disruptive, you'll want to contact the manufacturer.

A recurring occasional ticking sound is a bad sign. That suggests that the drive is defective, and may fail soon. If I had a brand new machine with a drive making that sound I would backup any important files immediately and initiate a warranty replacement.

If noise in general is a concern, you might want to consider getting SSDs instead of HDDs. Noise, power consumption, and reliability will all be better with SSDs, and prices have come down significantly recently.